# setup.py missing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed matplotlib from

http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

I tried to get to the first step

```
c:\Python34\Scripts>py Example_01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Example_01.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <mod
ule>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

Using this site, I found advice that I should run setup.py.  I found versions of setup.py in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\numpy but not in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib.

So, my question would be:

1. Should I have a `setup.py` in the `site-packages\matplotlib`
2. Should there be a separate `setup.py` for each site package?
3. How would Python know which to run...both numpy and matplotlib can be imports.

Comment: you need to install `six`, this has nothing to do with `setup.py`

Comment: ```sudo pip install six```

Comment: "I have installed matplotlib from ...." -- the Windows installers there are mutually exclusive with usage of `setup.py`.  Do one or the other.

Comment: Installed six using pip install six (started this prior to seeing the post with prefix sudo).  Six appears to be installed, but now I get the following: 

    from six.moves import zip
ImportError: No module named 'six.moves'; 'six' is not a package

Any further help would be appreciated